# Limit of $p_{k+1}(z)/p_k(z)$ with $p_k(z)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lceil zk \rceil}{k\choose i} p^i(1-p)^{k-i}$ and $z<p$

Tags: limits, probability-theory, summation

> How to find the limit of $\dfrac{p_{k+1}(z)}{p_k(z)}$ as $k$ tends to infinity, where, for every $k$, $$p_k(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lceil zk \rceil}{k\choose i} p^i(1-p)^{k-i}$$ for some $z$ and $p$ in $(0,1)$ such that $z<p$?

The top and bottom both converge to $0$ by the law of large numbers.

I was thinking of using L'Hopital with respect to $k$ but not sure how that would work because of the ceil function.

Comment: Limit when $\color{#f00}{?} \to \color{#f00}{what}$ ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X_n)$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli with parameter $p$, then $$p_k(z)=P(X_1+\cdots+X_k\leqslant kz)$$
Since $z<p$, the events $[X_1+\cdots+X_k\leqslant kz]$ are *large deviations* events and one knows that $$p_k(z)=e^{-kI(z)+o(k)}$$ 
where $I$ denotes the so-called *action* of the large deviations principle, defined in general as $$I(z)=\sup_{t<0}\left(tz-\log E(e^{tX})\right)$$
In the present case, $$E(e^{tX})=pe^t+1-p$$ hence $$I(z)=z\log\left(\frac{z}p\right)+(1-z)\log\left(\frac{1-z}{1-p}\right)$$
This suggests that $p_{k+1}(z)/p_k(z)$ should converge to $e^{-I(z)}$, but, to conclude this, one should refine the $e^{o(k)}$ error term in the asymptotic expansion of $p_k(z)$, to $$\frac{c(z)+o(1)}{\sqrt{k}}$$ for some positive $c(z)$ whose value will be irrelevant. And guess what, it happens that this holds true, since $$p_k(z)\sim\frac{e^{-kI(z)}}{\sqrt{2\pi z(1-z)}}$$ in the precise sense that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt{2\pi z(1-z)}\,e^{kI(z)}p_k(z)=1$$ hence indeed, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{p_{k+1}(z)}{p_k(z)}=e^{-I(z)}=\left(\frac{p}z\right)^z\left(\frac{1-p}{1-z}\right)^{1-z}$$

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean the rate of convergence of $p_k(z)$ is 1?

Comment: What do you call "the rate of convergence of $p_k(z)$"?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question

Comment: Really? I thought it used only simple English words...

Comment: If a sequence $x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n$ converges to a value $r$ and if there exist
real numbers $λ > 0$ and $α ≥ 1$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mid{\frac{x_{n+1} - r}{(x_n-r)^\alpha}}\mid = \lambda $$
Then $\alpha$ is the rate of convergence of the sequence. Is my definition of rate of convergence. So I guess $p_k(z)$ has rate of convergence $1$?

Comment: This seems to follow trivially from what is written in my post, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I am checking since I have read two definitions of rate of convergence today which seem to conflict. I have asked a separate question on this.

Answer (score 0):

If $X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$, then $\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$ and one can use it to estimate numerator and denominator. Basically, both are $\Phi(\frac{\sqrt{n}(z-p)}{\sqrt{p(1-p)}})(1+O(\frac1n))$, so the limit is 1.

Comment: This does not hold. One cannot apply the CLT at values varying with $n$.